# TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code - ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (64 bytes)

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, aes

First of all, I would like to point out that I have already consulted the posts with a similar title / problem but after hours of research I still can't solve my problem.

Here is the program code:

```
import sys
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
   print("Incorrect amount of arguments.")
   print("Example of use:")
   print("$ python {} LjFWQMzS3GWDeav7+0Q0oSoOM43VwD30YZDVaItj8e0".format(sys.argv[0]))
   sys.exit()

cpassword = sys.argv[1]

while len(cpassword) % 4 > 0:
   cpassword += "="

decoded_password = base64.b64decode(cpassword)

# This is a Microsoft hardcoded key used to decrypt GPO hash.
key = '\x4e\x99\x06\xe8\xfc\xb6\x6c\xc9\xfa\xf4\x93\x10\x62\x0f\xfe\xe8\xf4\x96\xe8\x06\xcc\x05\x79\x90\x20\x9b\x09\xa4\x33\xb6\x6c\x1b'

decryption_suite = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, '\00'*16)
plain_text = decryption_suite.decrypt(decoded_password)

print("Password is: {}".format(plain_text.strip()))
```

Here is the problem when I run the program.

```
user@computer:~/gpocrack-master$ python3 gpocrack.py LjFWQMzS3GWDeav7+0Q0oSoOM43VwD30YZDVaItj8e0
...Traceback (most recent call last)...
    raise TypeError("Object type %s cannot be passed to C code" % type(data))
TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code
```

After consulting many "solutions", supposed to solve the problem, for example changing the type of key : `key = b"4e9906e8fcb66cc9faf49310620ffee8f496e806cc057990209b09a433b66c1b"`

This time the problem is that :

```
...Traceback (most recent call last)...
    raise ValueError("Incorrect AES key length (%d bytes)" % len(key))
ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (64 bytes)
```

Having been to see on Internet I did not find any **clear** explanations concerning this problem...

I hope you will be help me to understand clearly what was wrong or help me solve the problem.

Thanks to the community!

Comment: ValueError in Python is raised when a user gives an invalid value to a function but is of a valid argument. It usually occurs in mathematical operations that will require a certain kind of value, even when the value is the correct argument. Imagine telling Python to take the square root of a negative integer.

Comment: I understand your answer but I understand a little less why my value seems to be bad, especially since it is a Python script that seemed to work well (with these same values)

Comment: There are many *clear* explanations that an AES key must be 16, 24, or 32 bytes in length. You had a 32-byte but then you presented it in your program as a string instead of key. When that didn't work you hex-encoded it but then made the hex-encoded version the bytes object. So, either use `key = b'\x4e\x99\x06\xe8\xfc\xb6\x6c\xc9\xfa\xf4\x93\x10\x62\x0f\xfe\xe8\xf4\x96\xe8\x06\xcc\x05\x79\x90\x20\x9b\x09\xa4\x33\xb6\x6c\x1b'` or `key = bytes.fromhex('4e9906e8fcb66cc9faf49310620ffee8f496e806cc057990209b09a433b66c1b')`.